# R - Getting rid of duplicate elements in vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove duplicate elements from any integer vector but without built-in functions: `duplicated()`,`unique()` and `anyDuplicated()`. Result however must be the same as result of `unique()`.

So far I managed to get values from vector in increasing order (which is not good enough). I did as follows (for given vector):

`vec <- c(1,2,2,4,1,1,5,6,3,9,0,4)`

I can use `vec <- sort(vec)` and then `rle(vec)$val` to get vector of values in increasing order. I also managed to get ordering vector from sorting function by `sort(vec,index.return=TRUE)$ix` and using that I'd like to apply this ordering to `result` vector (however it is not possible since `result` is shorter then `vec`).

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: huh? why don't you want to use those functions?

Comment: Ok, but why not use the built-in functions?  Is this just for fun?  Otherwise, knowing the need for this seemingly odd request will help greatly in providing useful answers.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of challenging task I received from my teacher. Furthermore using functions, loops and if-else statements is **not allowed** either. Forgot to mention earlier.

Comment: and you're responding to that challenge by posting the question on SO?! boo

Comment: well, I asked for ideas (meant hints), not solution itself

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
> vec[match(vec, vec) == seq_along(vec)]
# [1] 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 0
```

Comment: P.S. I would have preferred not to answer had I known from the start this was a homework. I thought about deleting my answer, then realized 1) OP had already had the chance to see my answer 2) if I leave my answer visible and said teacher finds it here, he'll know it was not the OP's work. So... I'm leaving my answer here.

Comment: It's nice solution, but I do not intend to use it, because it's not fully clear for me. I still prefer my approach to be finished. I thought someone would give me some hints how to go further but it seems I was wrong. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @flodel are you the teacher?! This is really cool and I had to run each bit to wrap my head round how it works. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

How to do things the unnatural way...

```
> vec[rank(vec,t="first")==rank(vec,t="min")]
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 0
> vec[{o<-outer(vec,vec,"-");rowSums((o==0) * (row(o)>col(o)))==0}]
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 0
> vec[!mapply("%in%",vec,lapply(seq_along(vec),function(x) head(vec,x-1)))]
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 3 9 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found very simple solution. It suffices to execute:
`union(vec,vec)`